# Setting tr and td width and height for email and browser

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am making HTML emails and I would like to preview them in my browser before sending them, so I would like them to look similar in the browser and in the email client. I've tried several ways to set the width and height of my rows and cells:

```
<table height="500" width="200">
    <tr>
        <td height="100">TEST</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 100px;">TEST</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

No success at setting the height either through the HTML properties or the style properties. The cell covers the whole height of the table.

**EDIT**

Because it seems to be working on an blank HTML page I'm posting more of the code here.
I'm actually using a Javascript on a PHP page to set the innerHTML property of a div. The full code of the function is:

```
function changeDivHTML()
{
begin = '<table width="595" height="842" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 10px; padding: 0px;padding-top: 6px; margin: 0px;">';

test = "<tr><td height=\"100\">Test</td></tr>";

testTwo = "<tr><td height=\"100\">Test</td></tr>";

end = "</table>";

parent.document.getElementById('divToChange').innerHTML = begin + test + testTwo + end;
}
```

The function is called and the innerHTML of the div changes fine. Everything is OK except the height of the cells is each 50%. They fill the whole table instead of taking 100px height each.

Setting the height in the tr tag has the same effect, which is no effect.

**MORE INFO**

This is the output on an empty HTML page. On my firefox browser the cells each take 50% of the height each. Covering the whole page instead of 100px

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body onload="window.print()">
<table style="border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 10px; padding: 0px;padding-top: 6px; margin: 0px;" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="842" width="595">
<tbody>
<tr height="100"><td height="100">Test</td></tr>
<tr height="100"><td height="100">Test</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

I need to avoid using CSS for this, as I said it's HTML code generated for emails and email clients are not friendly to CSS.

Comment: Paste you complete code

Comment: Try setting the height in your `<tr>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This **[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/FNUuM/1/)**

```
<table height="500" width="200">
<tr><td height="100">TEST</td></tr>
<tr><td style="height: 100px;display:block">TEST</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrKEV/1/

Only thing I can think of is that you missed out `<table>...</table>`

Comment: Hey, thanks for trying it out. Still having problems though, I updated the question with more information.

Comment: Try adding "px" to your height, not just the number

Comment: Would you mind taking another look? I've update the question with a copy of the output of the function on a blank html page and it's not displaying properly.

Answer (score 0):

hi 2 things you have missed out.

1. You have to set style for every tr or td wherever u want to add inline css
2. give values (height or width ) in px or % example 100px or 100%

Hope it will help you a bit

Thanks