# Best inline style format for HTML email?

Tags: html, css, email, inline-code

Which inline style format better for an HTML email template:

```
<table height="800"></table>
<table bgcolor="#000000"></table>
```

or

```
<table style="height:800px;"></table>
<table style="background:#000000;"></table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`height="800px"` is invalid.  You would want `height="800"` (no `px` in `height` attribute).  The CSS version should work in many clients, but @John reports that there is not 100% compatibility with it.

By far the best thing to do with e-mails is to not set a height at all though, since it doesn't really work.  Let your content flow.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I was just using height as an example!

Comment: @WesleyMurch This isn't about being in the stone age, it's about compatibility.  IE 3.0 doesn't know how to handle a non-numeric height attribute.  You need to just use a numeric value for that attribute if you go that route.

Comment: @Brad `height="800"` works 100% in all clients when applied to table/td elements, it is only `height:800px;` that doesn't work consistently. You should update the answer as it is not technically correct.

Comment: @John Interesting... It's been awhile since I've done an e-mail template.  Do you know what clients had trouble with CSS height?  I don't recall seeing any issues in Litmus, but I suppose it may have changed since then.

Comment: @Brad Not sure, I haven't checked recently as I remember it to be spotty and `height=""` is an easy alternative. My guess would be one of the Outlooks. I could be wrong on that - I'll have to check. I guess what I'm trying to say is that `height=""` is a 100% supported solution vs your comment about height in general not working.

Comment: @John Thanks.  The answer has been edited with the information you have provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both nowadays. However, if you want to be bullet proof use `height="800"` which works better for some older clients

Comment: do you mean height="800" or the CSS?

Comment: @MahaliaSamuels:height="800"

Comment: Yes, definitely meant height="800"

Answer (score 0):

the first one

```
<table height="800"></table>
```

Comment: @Brad just was in a hurry

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain why?

Comment: @MahaliaSamuels: check these answers -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870705/setting-tr-and-td-width-and-height-for-email-and-browser

Comment: @MahaliaSamuels:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989897/image-style-height-and-width-not-taken-in-outlook-mails

Answer (score 0):

`height="800"` works in all clients and is the way you should do it. `height:800px;` does not.

Same for background, the 100% supported method is `bgcolor="#000000"`, but only in `<table>` or `<td>` elements.

You should always use the top examples if you expect to get consistency across email clients.

This rule also applies to `align="left"` (correct) vs `text-align:left;` or `float:left;`, and `valign="top"` also works where `vertical-align:top;` is useless.